# Android Studio 3.0.1 gradle: connection reset

Tags: android, android-studio

I facing some error in Android Studio:

Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath'.

**ErrorLog:**

> Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0.
>     Required by:
>         project :app
>   Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/compiler/1.0.0/compiler-1.0.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/compiler/1.0.0/compiler-1.0.0.pom'.
>   Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.27.206] failed: Connection refused: connect
>   Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/android/arch/lifecycle/compiler/1.0.0/compiler-1.0.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/android/arch/lifecycle/compiler/1.0.0/compiler-1.0.0.pom'.

Comment: What you did till now? How to reproduce the problem?

Comment: > Could not resolve android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0.
  Required by:
      project :app
   > Could not resolve android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/persistence/room/compiler/1.0.0/compiler-1.0.0.pom'.

Comment: This comes everytime I run my project. Not able to understand whether it is studio's issue or network connection?